# How can I find out which app is being used on a website

Tags: dictionary, web, interactive

I'm looking to find out if the interactive map on this website is custom made or used from another source which I can replicate - http://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-guides/, I'm not a coder so was wondering if it's possible to find this from the page source info or possibly another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's using GeoChart from google api. like you can see in the source code:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/8c95b72e5c145d5b3d7bb8b4ea74fd63/format+en,default+en,ui+en,geochart+en.I.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

But if you are not a coder - it will be hard for you to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interactive world maps plugin for wordpress.

However this question does not belong on S/O.